# Issue with Joomla k2 userblog

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-k2

My k2 user blog is not showing any content(ItemList). When I checked the query and removed the  AND i.created_by_alias='' in DB , it is showing contents in phpmyadmin. But what is the real issue and how to fix it

Comment: are you getting any errors on the error log?

Comment: one notice is showing  Trying to get property of non-object in components/com_k2/templates/default/user.php on line 59 But that is related with userDescription